# fullCalendar listMonth events order

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm implementing a [listMonth](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list_view/intro/)  in fullCalendar. I want to invert the order, and show first on top of the recent events, not in the bottom. How can i do it?

Comment: not clear what are you asking. any screen shot ??

Answer (score 5):

To go from:    [image: Default Time Order]   to:    [image: Revered Time Order]

The only way to do this in the latest version (3.4.0) is to alter the source code.

Specifically, on line 6297 of the unminified source is the function

```
compareEventSegs: function(seg1, seg2) {...
```

To reverse the event sort order just swap the order of the `seg1` and `seg2` parameters around:

```
compareEventSegs: function(seg2, seg1) {...
```

Similarly, for the minified source, search for `compareEventSegs:function(t,e)` and do the same.

**Note that this will affect ALL views.**

Finally, if you want to implement more complex logic for the event sort order, this is the function to adjust.